# Why does it keep throwing a reading undefined variable error when they ARE defined?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, html5-canvas

So..... I get an error:

```
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#101:18'>101:18</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')"
```

When I run this:

```js
var Canvas = document.getElementById('ViewPort');
var Context = Canvas.getContext("2d");

Canvas.width = 250;
Canvas.height = 250;
Canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";

var Objects = [];

//Testing

Objects.push({

  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  style: "black",

})

Objects.push({

  x: 55,
  y: 55,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  style: "blue",

})

//End Testing

function RenderObjects() {

  for (var i = 0; i < Objects.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < Objects.length; j++) {

      if (Hitting(Object[i], Object[j])) {

        console.log("Hitting object " + j);
        console.log(Object[j])

      } else {

        Context.fillStyle = Objects[i].fillstyle;
        Context.fillRect(Objects[i].x, Objects[i].y, Objects[i].width, Objects[i].height);

      }

    }


  }

}

function Hitting(rectA, rectB) {

  return !(rectA.x + rectA.width < rectB.x ||
    rectB.x + rectB.width < rectA.x ||
    rectA.y + rectA.height < rectB.y ||
    rectB.y + rectB.height < rectA.y);

}

RenderObjects();
```

```html
<canvas id = "ViewPort"></canvas>
```

What is the issue? I have read through my code and I can't find any issue. It should render two objects on an HTML canvas; provided that they don't collide.

Comment: What is the `Object` array at the `renderObject` function (maybe you wanted to write `Objects`)?

Comment: You're missing an 's' on 'Objects': `Hitting(Object[i], Object[j])` should be `Hitting(Objects[i], Objects[j])` (also `Object` is a built in javascript class, be careful with your naming.)

Comment: thx i feel dumb

Comment: No worries, happens to us all. But in general try following the error back trace, and use an editor with good syntax highlighting. I pasted it in VSCode and instantly your typo was apparent due to color change (built in Class green vs var as light blue) and running it pointed directly to the line number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You only should fix some typo.

```js
var Canvas = document.getElementById('ViewPort');
var Context = Canvas.getContext("2d");

Canvas.width = 250;
Canvas.height = 250;
Canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";

var Objects = [];

//Testing

Objects.push({

  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  style: "black",

})

Objects.push({

  x: 55,
  y: 55,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  style: "blue",

})

//End Testing

function RenderObjects() {

  for (var i = 0; i < Objects.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < Objects.length; j++) {

      if (Hitting(Objects[i], Objects[j])) { //instead of Object[i], Object[j]

        console.log("Hitting object " + j);
        console.log(Objects[j]) //instead of Object[j]

      } else {

        Context.fillStyle = Objects[i].fillstyle;
        Context.fillRect(Objects[i].x, Objects[i].y, Objects[i].width, Objects[i].height);

      }

    }


  }

}

function Hitting(rectA, rectB) {

  return !(rectA.x + rectA.width < rectB.x ||
    rectB.x + rectB.width < rectA.x ||
    rectA.y + rectA.height < rectB.y ||
    rectB.y + rectB.height < rectA.y);

}

RenderObjects();
```

```html
<canvas id = "ViewPort"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just vote to close as typo. (Also if you're going to post an answer like this be explicit about what the typo is.)